# Material design ripple from jQuery to AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have some simple code for a material design ripple effect in CSS that can be used on every element needed just by applying an `.ripple` class on it (but it must have width and height). The code is the following:

```js
(function(window, $) {
  $(function() {
    $('.ripple').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      var $div = $('<div/>'),
        btnOffset = $(this).offset(),
        xPos = event.pageX - btnOffset.left,
        yPos = event.pageY - btnOffset.top;

      $div.addClass('ripple-effect');
      var $ripple = $(".ripple-effect");

      $ripple.css("height", $(this).height());
      $ripple.css("width", $(this).height());
      $div.css({
          top: yPos - ($ripple.height() / 2),
          left: xPos - ($ripple.width() / 2),
          background: $(this).data("ripple-color")
        })
        .appendTo($(this));

      window.setTimeout(function() {
        $div.remove();
      }, 2000);
    });
  });
})(window, jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
button {
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #89669b;
  color: white;
  padding: 18px 60px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.fab {
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
.material {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  margin: 20px auto;
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  background: #f45673;
}
.ripple {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.ripple-effect {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
  animation: ripple-animation 2s;
}
@keyframes ripple-animation {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(100);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Material Design Ripple</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Material Design Buttons</h1>
  <h3>Just add the class ripple to anything and use the "data-ripple-color" property to set the ripple color</h3>

  <button class="ripple">Login</button>
  <button class="ripple" data-ripple-color="#89669b" style="background:white; color:black;">Login</button>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**My question is:** can you change the JavaScript function code to AngularJS in the order not to use jQuery anymore and have the same result? The purpose is to use it in a main project.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write this code inside directive, basically that will do the DOM manipulation for you. This directive will start work whenever it find it found `class="ripple"`

**Directive**

```
app.directive('ripple', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                var $div = angular.element('<div></div>'),
                    btnOffset = $(this).offset(),
                    xPos = event.pageX - btnOffset.left,
                    yPos = event.pageY - btnOffset.top;

                $div.addClass('ripple-effect');
                var $ripple = angular.element(".ripple-effect");

                $ripple.css("height", $(this).height());
                $ripple.css("width", $(this).height());
                $div.css({
                        top: yPos - ($ripple.height() / 2),
                        left: xPos - ($ripple.width() / 2),
                        background: $(this).data("ripple-color")
                    })
                    .appendTo($(this));

                $timeout(function() {
                    $div.remove();
                }, 2000);
            });
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Actually, it works. I had a bad order in my html. If you still want the fiddle, it is [http://jsfiddle.net/vanntile/n2fugxhm/](http://jsfiddle.net/vanntile/n2fugxhm/)